# Cannot update Dataflow job via Update Flag

Tags: java, streaming, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to update DataFlow job by setting setUpdate flag in DataflowPipelineOptions to true. I have a function which checks for existing job with a name, and if the job is not there, I set setUpdate flag to false, otherwise true. This means for deploying the job for the first time, setUpdate flag is set to false, and all subsequent deployment will set flag to true.

```
options.setUpdate(jobExists(options));
```

The pipeline code is following:

```
    pipeline
    .apply("Read", pubsubDownload)
    .apply("Window", Window.into(FixedWindows.of(WINDOW_DURATION)))
    .apply("Extract", ParDo.of(new Extract()))
    .apply("Count", ApproximateUnique.perKey(0.06))
    .apply("View As Map", View.asMap()); //<-- ****Fails here
```

**Note: I just wanted to test the updated flag so did not change any part of the code among deployments. Just wanted to test that flag manages to replace old job with the new one.**

However this does not work. I can successfully deploy the job for the first time. When I attempt to re-deploy the job again, I get following error:

Workflow failed. Causes: (9a8ccc4f2e36c2d6): The new job is not compatible with <JOB_ID>. The original job has not been aborted., (9a8ccc4f2e36c371): **The stage View As Map/StreamingViewAsMap/Combine.Globally/Combine.PerKey/GroupByKey has changed in a way that is incompatible with update.**

Is **View.asMap** function not updatable? According to the documentation, **SideInput** is updatable. As error states, if the **View** is not updatable and **SideInput** needs a **View**, the documentation has false information.

Note that this works without **View.asMap** pipeline step.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what changes you've made between your pipeline between the original job and the new job?

Comment: @BenChambers There is no change. I wanted to test the update flag so I deployed once and deployed for the second time without touching any code. I updated original question to reflect an exact location that is failing at update.

Comment: We're investigating.

Comment: Is this issue still occurring?

Comment: Just curious how the `jobExists` function is implemented? I'm in the same situation but couldn't find any API available or documentation about this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check [Updating an Existing Pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/updating-a-pipeline)

Preventing Compatibility Breaks:

- Changing the pipeline graph without providing a mapping
- Changing the side inputs for a step
- Changing the Coder for a step.
- You've removed a "stateful" operation from your pipeline
- You're attempting to run your replacement job in a different geographic zone.

You can search for example in StackDriver Logging "does not have a stable unique name". Maybe some ParDo's are anonymous.

Comment: None of above point is broken. I have not updated the code among deployments. Please take a look at edit to the original question.